# SQLite create pre-populated FTS table

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-schema

Is there a way to create an FTS table in SQLite that is pre-populated with data from a SELECT query?

I know it’s possible to create a regular table that is prepopulated with data from a SELECT:
`CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT ref_id, name FROM other_table`

And we can create an FTS table like so:
`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE bar USING FTS3(ref_id, name)`

The point of doing this is to update my app’s SQLite database schema while avoiding reading in all of the data from `other_table`. I’m really hoping there’s some way to let SQLite do all the heavy lifting here (which is what it's really good at!).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it in one statement, but you can do it in two... after your `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE` statement, you can do: `INSERT INTO bar SELECT * FROM other_table`

Comment: Thanks! I actually just discovered that myself. I’m guessing it’s likely the most efficient way… MUCH more so than looping over the results from a select in my C code.