# how to convert existing sqlite database table to fts3 one?

Tags: database, sqlite, fts3

I have normal sqlite database and want to use fts3.
As mentioned in http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html tutorial  FTS table has to be created for using this search functionality.

Is there any way to convert existing table to FTS table?

Comment: Hi mate, I think you should check my revised answer! thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution is to populate the FTS virtual table by yourself. I mean to open a new thread which will read from the exist database then write to the FTS table.

Actually, I might find a better way, hope you are still watching this thread:

Please check this thread:
[SQLite create pre-populated FTS table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477377/sqlite-create-pre-populated-fts-table)

where the selected answer gave a better approach:

first do `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE` in your exist database,
then populate the virtual table using the original table within your database.