# import SQL Table to FTS4 virtual table

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

**EDIT:**
I have a python app that is creating a table in the Database.
It creates a random number of rows. I do not the know the exact the number of rows that are created in the table. Each rows correspond to the metadata of my pictures, in the example below, only 6 rows are created:

[image]

I want to use FTS4 full text search capability to parse the columns for a key words.

So Far, I understand that I need to create a virtual table and import every thing from the original table to the virtual one. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477377/sqlite-create-pre-populated-fts-table) SO thread I understand that I need do : `INSERT INTO bar SELECT * FROM other_table` .

So, what is the syntax to create the Virtual one and import the content from the CONTENTSEARCHINDEX table  to the CONTENTSEARCHINDEXvirt virtual table :

```
conn.execute('''CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTENTSEARCHINDEXvirt USING FTS4;''')
conn.execute("INSERT INTO CONTENTSEARCHINDEXvirt SELECT * FROM CONTENTSEARCHINDEX")
```

I got this error :

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table CONTENTSEARCHINDEXvirt has 1 columns but 7 values were supplied
```

So as CL said, this syntax tries to import this random number of columns to the default column is created .

Then What is the best Way to do that ?

I can get the list my -unknown- columns by using :

```
# Listing the number of columns from initial DB as a list.
connection = sqlite3.connect(DBtoReadAndParse)
cursor = connection.execute('select * from CONTENTSEARCHINDEX;')
namescolumns = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cursor.description))
```

Comment: Do you really want to index all 21 columns? And how should the database know how many columns you want?

Comment: @ CL: This is the purpose of my question. I am a newbee on SQLite ( and DB ). so I have to specify the number of columns to create in my virtual table ? If yes, What would be the syntax ? -since I do not know the number of columns my script will create, because, I do not know initially all the characteristics of my students.

Comment: Don't you know what columns your table has?

Comment: No. the App creates Db dynamically and deletes it afterwards. From One Api Call to the other, this App creates a different number of columns every time is is called.

Comment: Are you asking how to find out which columns a table has, or how to create an FTS table?

Comment: I know how to get this : cursor = connection.execute('select * from CONTENTSEARCHINDEX;') and then namescolumns = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cursor.description)) . But I cannot use "alter" to recursively add the columns in my virtual table. if this what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite documentation documents how to create FTS tables: [CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html), [Creating and Destroying FTS Tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#creating_and_destroying_fts_tables).

The virtual table should contain those columns in which you want to do a full-text search. To create it, construct a string of the form

```
CREATE VIRTAL TABLE name USING FTS4(key, metadata_0, and_so_on)
```

Comment: I went there before sending my question to SO. not sure my issue is on creation, but on filling my virtual DB. So I have to find a way to get the content of my columns and the number of columns in my initial DB then recursively fill my virtual DB depending on this number of Columns. ?