# How to create a Full Text Search (FTS) virtual table from existing table without explicit column name?

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search, virtual-table

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7477377/1652217) describes how to create a FTS table (`tabel2`) from existing table (`table1`) by explicitly providing column names which boils down to:

```sql
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE table2 USING FTS5(col1, col2);
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
```

However in my case I have a table with hundreds of columns that makes it hard to explicitly name them. I tried to use `select` with `pragma_table_info` :

```sql
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE table2 USING FTS5(SELECT name FROM pragma_table_info('table1');
```

However this throws the error :

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (parse error in "SELECT name FROM pragma_table_info('table1')")

How can I automatically create a virtual FTS table from existing table without explicitly mentioning column names? I can get the `CREATE TABLE` command from DBeaver. However this command contains types and constraints which are an [ERROR in FTS5](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html).

Comment: Construct and execute ddl statement in Python. There is no dynamic SQL in SQLite. You can construct a ddl statement using SQL, but you will have to copy it from SQLite output and paste it to SQL shell for execution.